# Couldn't get data from another table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, json

I am currently trying to get a data(M_Name) from a table called Merchant.

Following are my codes:

```
<?php
$response = array();

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('ichop') or die ('Could not connect to database');

$result = mysql_query("select * from offer") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $response["offers"] = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $offer = array();
        $offer["offer_id"] = $row["Offer_ID"];
        $offer["start_date"] = $row["Start_Date"];
        $offer["end_date"] = $row["End_Date"];
        $offer["o_desc"] = $row["O_Desc"];
        $offer["short_desc"] = $row["Short_Desc"];
        $offer["merchant_ID"] = $row["Merchant_ID"];
        $offer["m_name"] = mysql_query("SELECT M_Name FROM MERCHANT WHERE MERCHANT_ID = '".$row["merchant_ID"]."'");

        array_push($response["offers"], $offer);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
//no offer found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No offer found";

echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

When I run this PHP file using web browser, I couldn't get the desired name for the merchant even though the data is there in the database...it would just return me "null".

```
{"offers":[{"offer_id":"1","start_date":"2013-05-17","end_date":"2013-05-18","o_desc":"AAA","merchant_ID":"2","m_name":null}],"success":1}
```

What have I done wrong or what am I still missing? Please help..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use `LEFT JOIN` mysql function and get all relevant data at first query from both of your tables

```
 SELECT * FROM offer a LEFT JOIN MERCHANT b ON a.Merchant_ID = b.MERCHANT_ID
```

so you won't have to make any extra query and you can store your value directly in your array

```
$offer["m_name"] = $row['M_Name'];
```

Then I would like you to remember that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Thanks bro! you just saved me ^_^ I am using mysql_* for current project only...not going to do any development in future i guess :X

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_query("SELECT M_Name FROM MERCHANT WHERE MERCHANT_ID = '".$row["merchant_ID"]."'");` does not return a value from the DB, you need to follow it up with for example `mysql_fetch_array` like you did with the other query to the DB.

There is a solution more simple: use a `JOIN`, which combines two tables.

```
SELECT offer.*, MERCHANT.M_Name 
FROM offer 
LEFT JOIN MERCHANT ON(MERCHANT.MERCHANT_ID = offer.merchant_ID)
```

Comment: @Adder...how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$offer["m_name"] = mysql_query("SELECT M_Name FROM MERCHANT WHERE MERCHANT_ID = '".$row["merchant_ID"]."'")
```

`mysql_query()` does not return a string but a resource. You'll have to fetch the result.

Also, don't forget that mysql_* is now deprecated.

**[edit]**

As stated by Fabio, you'd rather use JOIN on your query. At the moment, you are making a request in your loop. That's useless (INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN are what you want) and very resource consumming.

Comment: @Herode...how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

look like you have to return an result from query instead of while,

```
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT M_Name FROM MERCHANT WHERE MERCHANT_ID = '".$row["merchant_ID"]."'"));
```

but had better you make some error hadling first

Answer (score 0):

You can use below one

```
$resMerchant = mysql_query("SELECT M_Name FROM MERCHANT WHERE MERCHANT_ID = '".$row["merchant_ID"]."'");

$rowMerchant = mysql_fetch_assoc($resMerchant);
$offer["m_name"] = $rowMerchant['M_Name'];
```